# Callback order in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a problem understanding the call-order of the callback methods in nodejs writing/appending text to a file:

```
fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, '/test', 'hello.txt'), 'Hello ', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log("1");


  fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/test', 'hello.txt'), 'World!', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log("2");
  });

  console.log("3");
});
```

Executing this piece of code I get the output order: 1, 3, 2

But wouldn't the logic call order be 1, 2, 3? Or doesn't the console.log("3") simply not "wait" till appendFile has finished executing?

Guess I totally got something wrong here.

Comment: No, it doesn't wait, that's *why* you have to use callbacks. All of the code in the `writeFile` callback is executed immediately, and the nested callback to `appendFile` is added to the to-do list for when that operation finishes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe With immediately you mean in the order of 1, append, 3? And later the function call in append?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you're seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log("3");` does not "wait", because it is not part of the callback for `appendFile`. Only the callback (i.e. `console.log("2");`) "waits" for `appendFile` to finish.

The sequence of your code is as follows:

1. write "Hello " to the file
2. when "Hello " is written: print `1` to the console.
3. when `1` is written to console: start appending "World!" to the file

Now, 2 processes are triggered, likely 4 will be executed first:

4. when process of appending "World!" has started: print `3` to the console
5. when process of appending "World!" has finished: print `2` to the console

Answer (score 0):

after executing `console.log("1")` , calls `fs.appendFile` but does not wait until it finishes. It allows asynchronous execution of the called function and go to line `console.log("3")`.

At the end of that function `console.log("3")` is executed as the callback.

clearly your `doSomthing` is not an asynchronous function to call and skip. So code have to wait for the finishing of that function.